# Refractive Index in Ionized Liquid from Micro Aspect

Tags: optics, refraction, ions

I learned about the refractive index of gases and dense materials, which is a function of the atom number per volume, wavelength of electromagnetic wave, etc. However, what is the refractive of solutions that contains ions? Is it the same as conductors or dielectrics and why? In my point of view, the mass of ions are much larger than electrons and we can neglect their vibration induced by electromagnetic wave. So we can treat the solution the same way as those without ions (such as sucrose solution), am I right?

Comment: Book Bottcher, "theory of electric polarization", if you can get it, mine is out of reach now.  I am not sure; your heavy- atom idea should work, but ions imply also dipoles, so change in orbitals of electrons, so different refractive index

Comment: Well I googled "refractive index salt water" and it changes from 1,33 to 1,38  with or without salt, that is very little difference

Comment: Hi @patta, I've got this book. Yes you are right the refractive index do changes. Actually I made a very sensitive sensor that can detect even weaker refractive index change. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I will look tomorrow at what Bottcher said..

Comment: What is confusing me is that since ions move freely in solutions, then how can we select electric dipoles? If we choose a single ion which contains positive and negative charges, then it's not electrical neutral. This violates the definition of electric dipoles. If we choose different ions with opposite charges, then which pair of ions should we choose.

Comment: I believe that each ion is surrounded by water molecules, which are polarized (the electrons are more oriented toward the ion) that should make them more reactive toward light?

Comment: Engineers in optical materials make any nasty thing to tweak refractive index...

Comment: Ok, so Bottcher, Chapter 8 par. 49; the book is actually a bit old, he do not discuss actual electrons movement in water around ions. One model is just to take the (molar) average of water and solute. Refraction can depend on concentration, when opposite ion of the electrolyte tend to recombine

Comment: May I know what is your application? Check if sucrose syrup refractive index has been counterfeited by addition of salts?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I’ll read this part dearly. I’m now working on water quality monitoring based on the refractive index change. I have to consider how ions influence the refractive index of water (not only sucrose). I tried to find a theoretical model to forsake the refractive index change when different ions exist in water, and detect it using our homemade sensor. If different ions influence refractive index differently, it is helpful to figure out the composition of the water sample.

Comment: Ok I see, so you are looking for really tiny variation of refraction!  I believe will be hard to find a simple theoretical model, as each ion will have its own polarizability and influence nearby electron cloud in different way

Comment: So I think your only way is to collect experimental values for different ions, and put them into Mossotti/Lorenz mixing formulas    https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319788451_Wavelength_and_concentration-dependent_optical_constants_of_NaCl_KCl_MgCl_2_CaCl_2_and_Na_2_SO_4_multi-component_mixed-salt_solutions           http://misclab.umeoce.maine.edu/education/VisibilityLab/reports/SIO_76-1.pdf

Comment: Maybe you can find some simple relation between refractive index and a) ion size and b) ion electronegativity  of c) water conductivity... maybe...

Comment: Thanks for your help! My plan is adding only one kind of salt in deionized water first, and measure the refractive index change. Combine with the theoretical conclusion to evaluate its influence. This is the first step. As you say, different ions may influence differently because of their different ion size etc. But, unfortunately, if there's no such kind of theoretical result, we should work on the theoretical model first. For one single kind of ion, it might be easier for me. Another issue, my book ends at Chapter 7, it is the 1973 version one. Can you tell me which edition you are using?